# Obtener Uri de Imagenes del External Storage y Mostrarla en Listview

Tags: android

Primero Tomo el Uri de la imagen con esto

```
public void SubirImagenes(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/");
        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione La Aplicacion"),10);
    }

    //parar abrir el estorage del mobile
    @Override
    protected  void onActivityResult(int resquestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(resquestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri path = data.getData();
        }
    }
```

Ahora Subo el uri a sqllite pero el uri lo convierto a string

```
String SubidaPath = path.toString();
```

y lo inserto como string ala base de datos

Ahora lo muestro en un listview con Adaptador y con SQLite Base de datos

```
Uri mostrarImagen = Uri.parse(obtengo el string de sqlite);
```

Convierto el string a Uri porque el imageview esta con setImageUri

al final muestro la imagen con el set

```
imgalbum.setImageURI(mostrarImagen);
```

al principio cuando la aplicación se abre y se escoge la imagen funciona bien hasta lo muestra en el listview el problema es que al cerrar la aplicación total(hablo de cerrar la aplicación en segundo plano) algo sucede que al abrir de nuevo la aplicación ya no reconoce la imagen ahí necesito ayuda

otra observación es que si se cierra la aplicación y sigue en segundo plano la imagen se muestra solo falla cuando la aplicación se cierra totalmente y al volver a abrir la app ya no reconoce la imagen

Comment: Que error te muestra la pantalla del logcat?

Comment: 2019-10-04 11:55:54.459 5089-5089/com.example.myapplication W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F109/ORIGINAL/NONE/1715184371

Comment: pero si al principio si la abre porque después no? me d la sensación que cuando se elije la foto de la galería como que hace la conexión con la imagen y claro al cerrar en segundo plano no conecta de nuevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa seria que guardes la imagen en tu db en una columna tipo BLOB:

String CREATE_TABLE:

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE SubidaImagenProducto"+
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                "ImagenProducto BLOB)";
```

En tu onActivityResult agrega:

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri path = data.getData();
            try {
                AgregarSubidaImagen(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), path));
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            mostrarImagen();
        }
```

En tu método AgregarSubidaImagen:

```
public void AgregarSubidaImagen(Bitmap imagen) {
        DAO admin = new DAO(this, "administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues subida = new ContentValues();
        subida.put("ImagenProducto", bitmapToBytes(imagen));
        BaseDeDatos.insert("SubidaImagenProducto", null, subida);
        BaseDeDatos.close();
    }
```

Para mostrar la imagen:

```
private void mostrarImagen() {
        DAO admin = new DAO(this, "administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select ImagenProducto from SubidaImagenProducto order by id desc Limit 1", null);
        Bitmap img = null;

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                try {
                    img = bytesToImg(cursor.getBlob(0));
                    imagenView.setImageBitmap(img);

                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Métodos para comprimir y descomprimir imagen:

```
private byte[] bitmapToBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    public static Bitmap bytesToImg(byte[] bytes) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
```

Comment: como subo a ala base de datos el byte[]?

Comment: public void AgregarSubidaImagen(){

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues subida = new ContentValues();
        subida.put("ImagenProducto", imagen);
        BaseDeDatos.insert("SubidaImagenProducto", null, subida);
        BaseDeDatos.close();
    }

Comment: Como hago para insertar el byte?

Comment: Se agrega actualización

Comment: Muchas gracias ya se resolvio mi problema  gracias a ustedes y sigo aprendiendo cosas nuevas